# Returning structs in function c

Tags: c, function, struct, return

I'm trying to return a `struct` from a function. 
It  looks like this..

```
struct read(struct returnera returnDuo, struct vara varuArray[]) { 
     char varunr[LISTNUMBER], varunamn[LISTNUMBER];
     FILE *varuLista;
     varuLista = fopen(returnDuo.filnamn, "r");
     if(varuLista!=NULL) {
         while(fscanf(varuLista,"%s\t%s\t%d\n",varunr, varunamn, 
                      &varuArray[returnDuo.antalVaror].lagerSaldo) == 3){ 
            strncpy(varuArray[returnDuo.antalVaror].varuNr,varunr,5);
            strncpy(varuArray[returnDuo.antalVaror].varuNamn,varunamn,30);
            returnDuo.antalVaror++;
        } 
        printf("Filen är laddad..\n"); 
        kommaVidare();
     }
     else {
        printf("Filen hittades inte, skapar en tom fil"); kommaVidare();
     }
     fclose(varuLista);
     return returnDuo;
 }
```

I'm trying to return the content in the `returnDuo` struct but I get the error message: "Expected identifier or '('". If I use `void` function its working as expected without returning anything but I cant figure out how to return this `struct`.

This is how I setup the structs.

```
struct vara {
    char varuNr[5];
    char varuNamn[50];
    int lagerSaldo;
};

struct returnera {
    int antalVaror;
    char filnamn[LISTNUMBER];
};
```

And how I setup them up in main.

```
struct vara varuArray[SIZE];

struct returnera returnDuo = {0,"0"};
```

I gladly take any tips on how to get this to work...

Comment: `struct read(...)` -> `struct returnera read(...)`???

Comment: Please apply some formatting. Then you will notice that the return value of `read()` is just `struct`. Then check whether you still have a question.

Comment: Please study and apply the concept of a [mcve].

Comment: I don't know why but I found it funny that the code was in swedish :D no offense intended.

Comment: Swedish code makes it better ^^

Comment: @JoakimWeidenius post the code `regNyVara();` or at least its declaration.

Comment: Sorry, i understand that it was a bit confusing, Look at this bit of code instead because it is giving me the same exact problem..  `returnDuo.antalVaror = read(returnDuo, varuArray);` Only this is related to the first question..

Comment: I solved it.. `returnDuo  = (returnDuo, varuArray);` works perfect. I,m not sure why though, i guess its because i need to return the whole struct?

Answer (score 4):

it should be

```
struct returnera read(struct returnera returnDuo, struct vara varuArray[])
```

not

```
struct read(struct returnera returnDuo, struct vara varuArray[])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for using a typedef.  Declaring a typedef to the struct provides a compact single-word name for the struct type.  Example:

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct Item_Struct {
    int val;
} Item;

Item Update( Item item, int val )
{
    item.val = val;
    return item;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Item item;
    printf( "Item -> %i\n", Update(item,4).val ); // Prints "Item -> 4"
    return 0;
}
```

Note that in C++ (as opposed to C) you can simply use the name of the struct by itself:

`returnera read(returnera returnDuo, vara varuArray[])`